# redirect http non www to https non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have just switched over to HTTPS. I previously set up the redirects to non-www + no trailing slash + no file extensions. I have changed the redirects to HTTPS. I am stuck with redirecting the http non-www to https non-www. The http www to https non-www redirect works just fine.

I've got the following code mostly from answers on here. The server is Apache 2.4.33 (Unix)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#Force non-www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added the website to a free Cloudflare account that automatically redirects and rewrites all http to https. Saved a headache, problem solved.